# Is Mister Bull actually a father?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, peppa-pig

Watching "Peppa Pig" with my kids a lot, I realised that Mister Bull is visiting  Peppa's playground at time where other parents go to pick up their kids.

So, the question arises: **Is Mister Bull a father?** And if so, **who is he the father of?**

***There is no small bull amongst the kids...***

Comment: Maybe he adopted. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peppa_Pig#Other_Characters) on Peppa Pig, mr Bull is listed under "other characters", not in one of the families of the children and their parents. There is also no "Cow" family.

This suggests that no, he doesn't have any kids of his own. (Good thing too, considering how many jobs he holds, he wouldn't have time for any!)